# How to run sub procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to vba. Well I m writing a sub procedure with arguments like 
Sub addcell  (ByVal target as range) and write some statements. My query is that how to run this procedure automatically without doing anything and without using a command button. Is there a way. Please help me with this.

Comment: When do you want it to run? Have a look at [Worksheet Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet_events.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left-hand side of the Visual Basic Editor you have the Project Explorer pane; this shows all the objects in your workbook. You will notice that there are at least two objects by default in any workbook - a ThisWorkbook object and a Sheet object for each worksheet in the workbook. Code that you want to run automatically should be placed in either ThisWorkbook or the appropriate Sheet object.

[image]

If you double-click on any of the workbook or worksheet objects, you will open a code window showing the code currently stored in that object. At the top of the page are two dropdowns, which will normally default to something like "(General)" and "(Declarations)". Open the "(General)" dropdown to get a list of objects - normally you'll see either "Worksheet" or "Workbook" depending on the object you've opened.

[image]

Select the object, then the "(Declarations)" dropdown will give you a list of events. They have pretty descriptive names, like "Change", "SelectionChange", "Calculate", "WorkbookOpen", etc. Select the event you want, and a new sub will be automatically created. Put your code inside this sub, and it will execute whenever that trigger is reached.

BE VERY CAREFUL. If, for instance, you put code in the Change event of a worksheet that ends up changing the sheet, you can get into an unproductive loop of the sheet constantly changing itself and re-triggering itself endlessly.

Comment: Just to add to this - you can avoid recursion by only targeting a particular cell or range or by disabling the events and re-enabling by using `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end

Comment: Thank you guys. Was a great pleasure to see it working now. Please keep on helping. Thank you and kadrinchey(thank you in Bhutanese language)